# Third Party Social Media API'S

Tags: social-networking

I have one web site in which I want to access data of major social media api's like Twitter,Google+,Facebook,YouTube etc....

Anyone know which are third party web sites(No problem with Paid solutions) which can provide me data?

Answer (score 0):

browse the website [programmableweb](http://www.programmableweb.com/),you can check who are providing their APIs.

Answer (score -1):

Tweed Feed saves tweets as nodes in drupal CMS https://www.drupal.org/project/tweet_feed and is even free. Best commercial all-in-one solution seems to be newswhip.spike  https://www.newswhip.com/api/ (desktop search demo for 14 days is free, API costs thousands of euros/month, depending on how many areas and languages you need to cover)